# How to export all sliced images in gimp?

Tags: gimp, export

I am slicing an image using guides. But after slicing, i have to export all the files one by one which is a pain. Any way I can export them all at once?

Comment: Maybe You can try a following trick, assuming all sliced images are on different layers of the same picture 1)  export your layers as animated.gif, 2)  use ffmpeg on animated.gif to expand them to folder as images series.

Comment: @BombaPs they are on the same layer :(

Answer (score 2):

Possible solutions:

- Use a script to export the images instead doing it manually (via GIMPs built-in scripting system).
- Use GIMP's web slice functionality.

For the second option, you can set your guides with e.g. *Image > Guides* and then use *Filters > Web > Slice*. An extra HTML file will be generated and the options for formats are extremely generic (a radio button list of `gif`, `jpg` and `png`), but each slice will be exported as an individual file automatically.

Comment: In newer GIMPs (I am using 2.10 on Windows) there is no Filters > Web > Slice option. Is there a way to get it back?